# Remove CSS class for Paritcular Html Element

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS.

I have added a CSS class to a `table` element. Then I added a child table into the parent table. The problem is that the parent tables CSS class also affects the child table.
I dont want this to happen.

How can I ensure that the CSS applied to the parent table does not affect the child table?

My Css is as Follows:

```
.gtable {
    width: 100%;
}
.gtable th {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
.gtableTH {
    text-align: center;
}
.gtable thead tr {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
}
.gtable thead th {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C0C0C0;
}
.gtable tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #FFFAE3;
}
.gtable td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.gtable tbody tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
.gtable tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) .gtable thead th {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #EFEFEF) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

and my HTML :

```
<table class="gtable">

                        <thead>

                            <tr>

                                <th>Drop Down Label</th>
                                <th>Drop Down Values</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>

                        <tbody class="ui-sortable">

                            <tr>

                                <td>Category 1</td>

                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody class="ui-sortable"><tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Complaint
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Service Request
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Enquiry
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                     <button class="button small" type="submit">Edit</button>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Can you post your html and css code? I am sure you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Create a selector that matches the child table and overwrite the parent rules.

Comment: You need to post your code, in order for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no clue without your code, but here's a demo of two tables with nested tables. one has the styles turned off: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7QWQv/

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** from the code you just posted, it looks like the problem is that `.gtable td` (and other selectors with spaces in them) select a `td` anywhere inside an element with the `gtable` class (which includes the child table). If you only want to select elements within the first table, either put classes directly on those elements, or use a child selector, like `.gtable > tbody > tr > td`.

Answer (score 2):

Use immediate child selector `>`
This means the CSS properties will be applied to only direct descendants of the selector on left side.

e.g.

```
.box1 > img  {
     border:5px;
}
```

only `<img>` tags directly inside of .box1 will have a border of 5px. If they are inside any other element, lets say `<a><img src=... /></a>` they will not have any border

use this CSS for your example :

```
    .gtable {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .gtable > th {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .gtableTH {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .gtable > thead > tr {
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        color: #333333;
    }
    .gtable > thead > th {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #C0C0C0;
    }
    .gtable > tbody > tr:hover > td {
        background-color: #FFFAE3;
    }
    .gtable > td {
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }
    .gtable > tbody > tr > td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    }
    .gtable > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) >.gtable > thead > th {
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #EFEFEF) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Css you are using `.gtable tbody, .gtable tr, .gtable td, .gtable th` which means you are applying css to all the childs (tr, td, th) inside your parent table. You should be avoiding it.

**Solution:**
Apply another class to the child table like `<table class="childtable">`
and in you css you will need to define css for the nested elements as - 
`.childtable tbody, .childtable tr, .childtable td, .childtable th` etc.